# include with double parenthesis kills live site

Tags: php

In our project all files gets included with double parenthesis.
When i changed it to single, to whole site is unreachable (local it all works).

Can someone explain to me, how this is possible?

**Example:**

This is what we have now:

```
if ((include_once $moduleInitializerFilePath))
```

Witch i changed to:

```
if (include_once $moduleInitializerFilePath)
```

Comment: Works with single or double parenthesis. So most likely you have some "exotic" php environment. Could be some preprocessor or an alternate implementation.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i was thinking too. I know it's possible with single, double or none. The fact it works local tells me it is the server. still curious how this is possible..

Comment: Well, did you check your php environment for the alternatives I pointed out?